# Why Junit still allow a class extend TestCase to use the annotation @Test in it?

Tags: junit

I know in Junit, the class extend TestCase cannot support @Before and @After. But it still allow to use @Test?

I know without @Test, if we want to run this class, we could override the runTest method and define the method to be invoked. This is not convenient. Because if we mark the @Test in method of this class., it could run directly. Can anyone tell me the mechanism about how to invoke the method with @Test about this class?

By the way, If I want put a lot of tests into a TestSuite, Should I choose a class extend TestCase or define a arbitrary class with @Test as the Single Test Class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TestCase class is from Junit 3 and should not be used in Junit 4 + classes.

If you extend TestCase, and use the Junit 3 Test runners then your test method names need to start with the word "test".  (Junit 3 test runners use Java reflection to find and invoke all methods that start with the word "test")

Relying on TestClass hindered test class designs because you were forced to extend that class which made somethings hard to test.  There also wasn't anything equivalent to Junit4's @BeforeClass or @AfterClass which meant you had to do all the more complicated multi-test fixture set up and tear down yourself.

To run many Junit4 test classes at once as a Test Suite, you can create a new empty class with the @RunWith and @SuiteClasses annotations as shown below:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(
{
   TestClassA.class,
   TestClassB.class

}
)

public class MyTestSuite{

}
```